# Isomorphism of presheaves

Tags: sheaf-theory

I just want you to tell me if a morphism of presheaves $\varphi:\mathscr{F}\to\mathscr{G}$ is an isomorphism iff every map $\varphi_U$ is bijective. I think it is true. Here my proof for the nontrivial implication:

Let $V\subseteq U$ and $s\in \mathscr{G}(U)$. We have to show $\varphi_U^{-1}(s)|_V=\varphi_V^{-1}(s|_V)$.

We have $s|_V=\varphi_U(\varphi_U^{-1}(s))|_V = \varphi_V(\varphi_U^{-1}(s)|_V)$ because $\varphi$ is a morphism. Applying $\varphi_V^{-1}$ to both sides finishes the proof.

Is that proof and hence the assertion correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Isn't it clear from the definition ? An isomorphism of presheaves is an morphism if it has an two-sided inverse.

Comment: @Susobhan You have to prove that the inverse is a morphism. That's not for all structures the case. Consider for example topological spaces. A morphism of topological spaces is a continuous map. But there are bijective continuous maps which are not open hence no isomorphisms (also called homeomorphisms). What I proved here is that this can't happen with morphisms of presheaves.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain: But our maps of presheaves are maps $\phi_U: \mathcal{F}(U) \rightarrow \mathcal{G(U)}$ , which are maps of abelian groups or maps of rings and any bijective homomorphism of groups and rings is automatically isomorphic.

Comment: @Susobhan In general there is no structure on $\mathscr{F}(U)$ so such arguments don't work. But even if we have a presheaf of abelian groups your argument doesn't help us. I don't want to show that the $\varphi_U$ are isomorphisms. I want to show that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism of presheaves. So I have to show that the inverse is a morphism of presheaves which means by definition that the $\varphi_U$ commute with restriction. Look for example [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~blnli/buildings/bag.pdf) at Definition 2.17.

Comment: That $\phi^{-1}(U)$  and $\phi^{-1}(V)$commutes with the restriction maps from $\mathcal F(U)\rightarrow \mathcal F(V)$ and  $\mathcal G(U)\rightarrow \mathcal G(V)$ is very trivial. It just follows from the commutativity of $\phi(U)$'s with the restriction map. I didn't understand that you were trying to prove that part.

Comment: In your proof you wrote- $s|_V=\varphi_U(\varphi_U^{-1}(s))|_V = \varphi_V(\varphi_U^{-1}(s)|_V)$. Now, $(\varphi_U^{-1}(s)|_V)$ is an element of $\mathscr F(V)$. What do you mean by $\varphi_U(\varphi_U^{-1}(s))|_V$? You cannot operate $\varphi (U)$ on an element of $\mathscr F(V)$

Comment: Similarly there is a problem in $\varphi_V(\varphi_U^{-1}(s)|_V)$ this too.

Comment: And the sections on presheaves always have a structure of abelian groups or rings or algebras. I haven't come across a sheaf of topological spaces yet. And for Sheaf of abelian groups, rings, algebras, what you stated will always trivially follow.

Comment: By $\varphi_U(\varphi_U^{-1}(s))|_V$ I mean that I restrict $\varphi_U(\varphi_U^{-1}(s))$ (an element of $\mathscr{G}(U)$, namely $s$) to $V$ by the restriction map provided by $\mathscr{G}$. That's standard notation, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, everything looks fine. I was just confused with so many braces together. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to show that: an morphism $\varphi$ of presheaf is an isomorphism iff $\varphi_U$ is an isomorphism for any  open subset $U$

Comment: You should develop your question a bit more in general to add context.